# What is mp_trans_seo_url?

Tags: html, seo

I came across this while looking on asos.com  I did some googling to try and find out what it is but there appears to be no information anywhere. I was just wondering if anybody had a better idea why they use it?

This is how it appears in their code:

```
<div class="title">
        <h1><span id="ctl00_ContentMainPage_ctlSeparateProduct_lblProductTitle"
class="product_title"><!--mp_trans_seo_url_title_start-->ASOS Canvas Backpacks
with Contrast Pockets<!--mp_trans_seo_url_title_end--></span></h1>
        <span><meta itemprop="name" content='ASOS Canvas Backpacks with Contrast
Pockets | ASOS'/></span>
```

Comment: not very well formulated question: "...why they use it" what do you refer to by "it"? (code snippet?). If you reformulate it - it will have higher value for readers not really familiar with the issue

Comment: Found this too and was interested what is that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply a **HTML** comment; possibly generated by a server side language like PHP (or other) indicating where the result of a variable (for the page title in this case) is placed.

The variable is possibly called "mp_trans_seo_url_title" in their system of choice and the **HTML** comments there, indicate where it 'begins' and 'ends' its output.

That is all. Nothing suspicious or out of the ordinary here.